# After restarting the master node of Apache IoTDB, what should I do for the belonging nodes?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

In cluster mode of Apache IoTDB, if the master node needs to be restarted, do all belonging nodes need to be stopped before restarting this master node?

Besides, anything I need to set up before restarting? Such as setting modification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to stop all belonging nodes. After the master node restarts in Apache IoTDB, other belonging nodes will automatically restart, and the historical data will not be lost.